# UINavigationController type menu in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I'm trying to create a popup menu with some kind of navigation inside it. For this, I'd like to mimic the style of the [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller) on iOS. If you're not familiar with it, it creates a hierarchal menu with sliding pages, like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Art/navigation_interface_2x.png))</sub>

I'd like to make something similar in HTML and JavaScript. The elements I'd like to take from iOS design are

- the sliding animation that occurs when going between pages.
- the back button that appears once navigation has occurred

I need something that doesn't involve page refreshes or moving between pages, but the menu only needs to be one level deep. Has anyone created this type of menu in JavaScript? I'd prefer vanilla JS, but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an hash from that menu, then iterate trough it like this.

At first you display the first level of the hash.
When the user clicks a link navigate in the hash at that position, fetch all it's children's and populate another instance of the menu behind the visible one.

Then it's a simple job of moving the new menu to a side so that it's visible.

And repeat...

As for the back button, you just fetch the parent of the current position i the hash...

Comment: I'll try an approach like this. If it works out, I'll accept this. Give me a couple hours ;)

Comment: Yep. I'm working on it. You can see a partial example by pressing the ? Button on http://luke.deentaylor.com/wikipedia/

Comment: Looks good, seems to me you're on the right track :) When confident.. please accept my answer !
Thanks